# Launcher and Panel disappeared 14.04 even after running compiz

Tags: 14.04, unity, launcher, panel

I went through the compiz manager and installed utility, but it still is not working, no Panel or Launcher are shown even after restarting.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps below :

1. Open terminal
2. To reset Unity and Compiz settings 'dconf reset -f /org/compiz/'
3. To restart Unity 'setsid unity'
4. To reset to default icons on Unity launcher 'unity --reset-icons'
5. Logout or reboot

Hope it helps.